# Unanswered questions, other categories

Tags: discussion, unanswered-questions

There are almost 3900 unanswered question on our website. I have red [this thread](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3138/unanswered-questions), and I want to add two categories of such questions. What I want to know is what we have to do with these questions.

1. Old homework questions, so answering them completely is not really a problem.
   [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/19663/cauchys-integral) is an example.
2. Questions not really clear, but the OP is not a member anymore, like [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/10484/does-this-semiring-theoretic-concept-have-a-name).

Comment: The problem with retagging them is that they come up to the top: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/2296/retagging-causes-bumping

Comment: What lhf said.  Let sleeping dogs lie.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For the second type of questions, especially those with no answers (which is slightly different from what the software calls unanswered), just vote them down. The system will automatically clean them up. (See [this discussion](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/2018/1543) here, where [this MSO discussion is linked to](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81887/what-happens-to-unanswered-questions-from-deleted-accounts/82408#82408).)

For the first type: I don't think it is really a problem. It may also give new users who wish to contribute by answering questions some low hanging fruits to attack first. Unless, of course, they are duplicates, in which case they should be closed as such.

Comment: 1. I love low-hanging fruit! (Interestingly, we have user "lhf" commenting on this question) 2. Thanks for the info about system clean-up.